# Play just a part of the sound (both in and out) with OpenAL (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, audio, delay, openal

I have a recording that has some unuseful voices at the beginning, and at the end.
How can I play just the middle part of the sound?

I have AL_SEC_OFFSET, that is suitable for the entry point, I already use it, but what about the endpoint?

Is there any smart OpenAL settings for this? Hopeso.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a workaround that fires a timer that stops playing before end.
Any simplier?

Answer (score 0):

OpenAL doesn't have built-in support for stopping playback at a specific sample point. A timer is your best bet in this case, even though it will be somewhat inaccurate.

If you want sample-perfect stopping, you could just load the middle part of the audio file into an ALBuffer rather than the entire thing. I have some code which does that here:

https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/OALAudioFile.m#L188